# How to get the link_rewrite field of a product in another language?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using `$product->getFieldByLang('link_rewrite', $id_lang)`. But it always returns the same `link_rewrite` of the current displayed language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because your $id_lang is not the good one or Product object is fully loaded with one language already. Anyway you can solve this in another way :

```
$product_rewrite = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT link_rewrite WHERE '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang WHERE id_product = '.(int) $product->id.' AND id_lang = '.(int) $id_lang);
```